# Проблема в выборе отношения или не правильная структура базы данных?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, laravel

В течение недели из-за дня в день переписываю все заново. Застрял на одном месте из-за того, что не получается правильно спроектировать базу данных. Получается так, что вроде все правильно, но когда дело доходит до завершения — упираюсь в неправильную структуру.

**Есть 3 таблицы:**

Производитель.

— Имеет `id` и `name`.

Коллекция.

— Имеет `id`, `manufacturer_id` и `name`.

Цвет.

— Имеет `id`, `collection_id` и `name`.

**Логика:**

У одного производителя может быть много коллекций. Одна коллекция может принадлежать одному производителю. У коллекции может быть много цветов. Один цвет может принадлежать только одной коллекции.

Сразу скажу, что цвет — это не цвет в привычном понимании, а именно физическая вещь. Если бы это был цвет в привычном понимании, то логично, что один цвет может принадлежать разным коллекциям, но это не тот случай. В нашем случае цвет — это то, что мы используем в качестве имени для безымянного предмета. Коллекции — это не коллекция в понимании Laravel, а просто название таблицы и модели.

```
— 1. Производитель.
— — 1. Коллекция.
— — — 1. Цвет.
— — 2. Коллекции.
— — — 2. Цвет.
— 2. Производитель.
— — 3. Коллекция.
— — — 3. Цвет.
— — 4. Коллекция.
— — — 4. Цвет.
```

Мне показалось логичным использование связи `hasMany()` (один-ко-многим), но все оказалось немного сложнее.

**Страницы:**

Нам не известны цвета и коллекции. Мы видим только их общее количество.

```
(Страница производителя)
Производитель — Коллекции — Цвета
Имя_____________2(две)______2(два)

(Страница коллекции)
Производитель — Коллекции — Цвета
Имя_____________Имя_________1(один)
Имя_____________Имя_________1(один)
```

Когда мы открыли страницу цветов.

```
(Страница цвета)
Производитель — Коллекции — Цвета
Имя_____________Имя_________Имя
Имя_____________Имя_________Имя
```

На странице производителя все очень просто и понятно. Мы можем связать модель производителя с моделью коллекции через `hasMany()` и с моделью цветов через `hasManyThrough()`. Потом можем посчитать общие количество коллекций и цветов этого производителя с помощью `withCount()`.

На странице коллекции тоже все очень просто. У нас есть обратная связь с моделью производителя `belongsTo()` и связь с моделью цветов через `hasMany()`. Мы используем `withCount()` для подсчёта общего количества цветов принадлежащих этой коллекции.

На странице цветов — тупик. Мы можем получить коллекции к которой принадлежит цвета т.к у нас есть обратная связь с коллекциями через `belongsTo()`, но у нас нет обратной связи с моделью производителей. В Laravel нет обратной связи для `hasManyThrough()`.

Получается, что либо у меня заведомо не правильно виденье решения этой задачи, либо проблема со структурой базы данных. Это мой первый опыт разработки, поэтому я хотел бы поступить правильно, а не сделать лишь бы как. Как вы решили бы эту задачу? Желательно максимально правильное решение дабы не учить новичка плохому. Однако я буду рад любым идея и предложения.

Comment: *у нас нет обратной связи с моделью производителей. В Laravel нет обратной связи* Не всегда надо плясать **ОТ** известного - иногда надо наоборот, идти **К** известному. Т.е. получать всё, а затем отбрасывать то, что привело **НЕ** в нужную точку. Запрос для получения цвета по производителю и запрос для получения производителя по цвету отличаются только тем, что в первом во WHERE условие по производителю, и на выходе несколько записей, а во втором условие по цвету и на выходе строго одна запись. В остальном текст запроса совпадает, ну с точностью до количества пробелов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас есть `belongsTo()` от цвета к коллекции, и есть `belongsTo()` от коллекции к производителю.

```
$colorManufacture = $color->collection->manufacture;
```

Если нужна коллекция и надо eager load

```
$colors = Color::with(['collection'=>function($query){
    query->with('manufacture');
}])->get();
foreach($colors as $color){
    $colorManufacture = $color->collection->manufacture;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Структура базы данных правильная. Вот SQL запросы:

**Страница производителя:**

```
SELECT
    m.name as manufacturer_name,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(c.id)) as collections_count,
    COUNT(cs.id) as colors_count
FROM manufacturers m
INNER JOIN collections c ON c.manufacturer_id = m.id
INNER JOIN  colors cs ON cs.collection_id = c.id
GROUP BY m.name
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Страница коллекции**

```
SELECT
    m.name as manufacturer_name,
    c.name as collection_name,
    COUNT(cs.id) as colors_count
FROM manufacturers m
INNER JOIN collections c ON c.manufacturer_id = m.id
INNER JOIN  colors cs ON cs.collection_id = c.id
GROUP BY m.name,c.name
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Страница цвета**

```
SELECT
    m.name as manufacturer_name,
    c.name as collection_name,
    cs.name as color_name
FROM manufacturers m
INNER JOIN collections c ON c.manufacturer_id = m.id
INNER JOIN  colors cs ON cs.collection_id = c.id
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]